# Вызов второго окна при выполнении условия и ожидание программы нажатия кнопки на нем с последующей передачей текста из Qlineedit pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

У меня есть код выполнения и два окна с одно QMainWindow, второе Qwidget Мне надо, чтобы при срабатывании условия в коде у меня вылезло второе окно с просьбой ввести данные для продолжения и кнопкой для продолжения.
Я много искал в интернете и дошел только до того, что вызывал второе окно, у меня продолжал выполняться код без обработки введённых данных и без ожидания нажатия на кнопку "Продолжить".
Дизайн делал через QtDesigner

```
 if "vk.com/login" in driver.current_url:
            #Тут должна быть обработка ошибки и возвращать значения которые мы ввели во втором окне
            login_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
                "#email")
            paswd_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
                "#pass")
            login_input.send_keys(ui.email.text)
            paswd_input.send_keys(ui.password.text)
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
                "#login_button").click()
            time.sleep(2)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    Dialog = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    ui.proved_with_login.clicked.connect(log_in)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Есть класс QInputDialog